# css: Print Media Target

Tags: html, css

If I don't specifically specify `media="print"` in the CSS reference e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/print.css" />
```

will `print.css` apply its styles when I print the page (from the browser: **File > Print...**)?

And, if I only specify `media="print"` without `screen`, will the styles apply when the page is viewed on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a `media` attribute in your `link`, the CSS isn't limited to a particular media type, and therefore would be used for both `screen` and `print`.